# How to concatenate column data and return in linq select

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a table where it has the columns like IsAgreed, IsOther, IsEquipped. On the UI I am showing 3 check boxes where one can select single or multiple check boxes. The data is getting saved to db as expected. Now I am trying to select the data in entity framework as follows

```
from tbl context.TableNames select new {
Conitions= tbl.IsOther ? tbl.OtherText : tbl.IsAgreed ? "Agreed :
tbl.IsEquipped? "Equipped" : "" }
```

Which is giving only one selection when the multiple selection are made. I would like to concat and result the data so that it can be

```
OtherText, Agreed, Equipped
OtherText, Equipped
Agreed, Equipped
```

Is it possible to concatenate and give the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of strings based on conditions, after it can be formatted as desired. Please pay attention to the comment i wrote in the code sample.

```
var conditions = context.TableNames.Select(tbl => new
{
    tbl.IsOther,
    tbl.IsAgreed,
    tbl.IsEquipped
})
.AsEnumerable() //Should be used with caution. Because it will load each record to memory. It also switches "LINQ to Entities" to "LINQ to Objects", so we can use string.Join.
.Select(c => new
{
    Conditions = string.Join(", ", new string[] { c.IsOther ? "OtherText" : "", c.IsAgreed ? "Agreed" : "", c.IsEquipped ? "Equipped" : "" }.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
});
```